# Console states method not available but it seems like it should be

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've got a rails app and I'm trying to add a thumbnail scroller.  It prints the div, but the js is not working.  Here's the file:

```
<div id="tS2" class="jThumbnailScroller">
    <div class="jTscrollerContainer">
        <div class="jTscroller">
          <% @illustrations.each do |illustration| %>
              <% if illustration.aws_image_thumbnail_url %>
                <%= link_to image_tag(illustration.aws_image_thumbnail_url, :title => illustration.name), illustration %>
              <% else %>
                <%= link_to image_tag(illustration.image.url(:thumb), :title => illustration.name), illustration %>
              <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($){
window.onload=function(){
    $("#tS2").thumbnailScroller({
        scrollerType:"hoverPrecise",
        scrollerOrientation:"horizontal",
        scrollSpeed:2,
        scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc",
        scrollEasingAmount:600,
        acceleration:4,
        scrollSpeed:800,
        noScrollCenterSpace:10,
        autoScrolling:0,
        autoScrollingSpeed:2000,
        autoScrollingEasing:"easeInOutQuad",
        autoScrollingDelay:500
    });
}
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Here's the error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'thumbnailScroller' 138:168
window.onload 138:168
window.onload
```

Here's the `thumbnailScroller` method within `jquery.thumbnailScroller.js`:

```
(function($){  
 $.fn.thumbnailScroller=function(options){  
    var defaults={ //default options
        scrollerType:"hoverPrecise", //values: "hoverPrecise", "hoverAccelerate", "clickButtons"
        scrollerOrientation:"horizontal", //values: "horizontal", "vertical"
        scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc", //easing type
        scrollEasingAmount:800, //value: milliseconds
        acceleration:2, //value: integer
        scrollSpeed:600, //value: milliseconds
        noScrollCenterSpace:0, //value: pixels
        autoScrolling:0, //value: integer
        autoScrollingSpeed:8000, //value: milliseconds
        autoScrollingEasing:"easeInOutQuad", //easing type
        autoScrollingDelay:2500 //value: milliseconds
    };
```

And here you can see that that js file is being loaded in to the rails app (output from chrome developmnet tools 'resources' tab:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/haggard/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
  <title>Visual Haggard</title>
  <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/reset.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/archive.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/blog_posts.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/booklist.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/comments.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/contact_forms.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/editions.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/illustrations.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/css/no-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.thumbnailscroller.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/novels.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/sessions.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/users.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/archive.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/blog_posts.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/booklist.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/comments.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/contact_forms.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/editions.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/illustrations.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.easing.1.3.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.thumbnailScroller.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/novels.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/sessions.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/users.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="IlafOuTVut9RwVQZwQrI4JpuieQp2lHla7HxIiCI2e0=" name="csrf-token" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

Does anyone see why this method is not available?

Comment: Are you sure you have jquery ui on your apps?

Comment: I'll edit to show the whole .js load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have tried use **Thumbnail scroller jQuery plugin** on my training apps and success.

First, remove `jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js`from your apps,

Make sure this gem on your gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

Remove `Gemfile.lock` and run bundle install

Make sure on `application.js` lookslike :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
```

Try this for method jquery thumbnail, Put this between `head` tag

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("#tS2").thumbnailScroller({
        scrollerType:"hoverPrecise",
        scrollerOrientation:"horizontal",
        scrollSpeed:2,
        scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc",
        scrollEasingAmount:600,
        acceleration:4,
        scrollSpeed:800,
        noScrollCenterSpace:10,
        autoScrolling:0,
        autoScrollingSpeed:2000,
        autoScrollingEasing:"easeInOutQuad",
        autoScrollingDelay:500
    });
});</script>
```

Comment: The javascript works now but it's still behaving funky.  For example if you reload a page, it only shows a few of the images and the js stops working.